# How can I catch both matches for this regular expression?

Tags: regex

I wrote the following regex:

`\[url=.*?\/users\/(.*?)\/\]@.*?\[\/url\]|\[quote="(.*?)"\].*?\[\/quote\]`

And I'm applying it to the following text with `multiline` and `global` modifiers:

```
[quote="foo"][url=http://localhost:8084/users/bar/]@bar[/url]test[/quote]

Hello World
```

I would like to match both `foo` and `bar`, but it's only matching `foo`.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Use two separate regexps, or use a regex for overlaaping matches. If `[url...]` is always inside `[quote..]`, join the alternatives and use two  capturing groups (see https://regex101.com/r/8IJUyJ/1)

Comment: You could just remove the `.*?\[\/quote\]` from the regex if you can safely assumed a well-formed document: https://regex101.com/r/ESS8i0/1

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, attempts; please try following regex.

```
\[quote="([^"]*)"\]\[url=https?:\/\/[^:]*:[0-9]+[^@]*@([^[]*).*?\[\/quote\]
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above solution.

```
\[quote="        ##Matching [quote=" with escaping [ here.
([^"]*)          ##Creating 1st capturing group which has everything just before " in it.
"\]\[url=https?  ##Matching "][url=https? where s is optional and ] and [ are being escaped.
:\/\/[^:]*:      ##matching :// before : everything including : here.
[0-9]+[^@]*@     ##matching digits(1 or more occurrences) followed by anything just before @ including @.
([^[]*)          ##Creating 2nd capturing group which has everything just before [ in it.
.*?\[\/quote\]   ##using lazy match .*? to match [quote] where escaping [ and ] here.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the two strings using a single regex like

```
\[quote="([^"]*)"\]\[url=[^\]\[]*?\/users\/([^\/]*)\/\]@.*?\[\/url\].*?\[\/quote\]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5M5vR1/2).

*Details*:

- `\[quote="` - a fixed string `[quote="`
- `([^"]*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than `"`
- `"\]\[url=` - a `"][url=` string
- `[^\]\[]*?` - any zero or more chars other than `[` and `]` as few as possible
- `\/users\/` - `/users/` string
- `([^\/]*)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than `/`
- `\/\]@` - `/]@` string
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\[\/url\]` - `[/url]` string
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\[\/quote\]` - a `[/quote]` string.